# Separating Reads & Writes to Mysql With out touching web server's configuration

Tags: java, mysql

I heard that there is a some type of mysql load balancer that splits read and writes and sends each request to different mysql instance (master, slave). So we can use master slave configuration with out updating each web app server.

So each app server uses one ip and sends all request to same server. But that servers splits the request and sends to corresponding sql server

If there is a system like that what is it called?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy). Article describing its use:

http://jan.kneschke.de/2007/8/1/mysql-proxy-learns-r-w-splitting/

Software is available from the MySQL website, but it's not clear if the project is still alive or not:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/